# How do i access a sequence in Client File?

Tags: java, corba

I have used a sequence(array) in Corba ,how do I access it in Client File?
What is the syntax for the same?

the idl file contains

```
   typedef sequence<string> name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this IDL https://github.com/JacORB/JacORB/blob/master/demo/any/src/main/idl/server.idl it is accessed like https://github.com/JacORB/JacORB/blob/master/demo/any/src/main/java/org/jacorb/demo/any/Client.java#L94